# Battery not charging on ASUS laptop GL752V

Tags: windows-10, laptop, battery, windows-10-upgrade, charging

It has been a few months now that my laptop's battery isn't charging anymore. It first happened after a windows update (can't recall which one) which would then show "plugged in, not charging". At the time, I searched for fixes online and found resolution involving uninstalling battery's drivers and remove said battery and restart the laptop. Since my laptop has an internal battery (yeah, didn't noticed that at the time of purchase) I simply gave up and thought that an update will eventually came to fix this all by magic. That was a mistake.

So a few windows updates later, nothing would change except that now it would read "plugged in, charging". But.... still stuck at 0%. I let that go for a while since I easily manage to use my device always plugged in. I would rather using it like this instead of open it to unplug that internal battery. I never opened my laptop before.

But this morning I had enough. So I got all my gear and went for the big job, I followed [this](https://www.cnet.com/how-to/how-to-fix-a-windows-10-laptop-battery-thats-plugged-in-but-not-charging/) tutorial thinking I would resolve the problem. It looked like a known issue from a previous windows update. So I uninstalled battery's drivers, turned off the device, opened the device to unplug the internal battery, realized at the same time I am never buying an ASUS product anymore (internal battery... are you serious? Took me 2 hours unplugging and plugging it back...) and power on the device again. No change. "plugged in, charging" but stuck at 0%.

I searched for other fixes, nothing relevant. I played a bit with the connector as many answers was about possible bad connection. Nothing. I put a little pressure on it, still nothing. And there is no dust in the connector. I highly doubt this is an hardware problem since laptop was never opened before and there was no sign of burning or corrosion inside. There even was no trace of dust in it, I take good care of my electronics. And problem occurred after an update and from what I saw online it was a known issue, again. So I went for a huge clean up. I formatted disk, went for a fresh windows install updated to version 1903.

Still stuck at 0%. But now it read "plugged in" and... nothing else! no "not charging", no "charging", only "plugged in". I went on ASUS site for drivers, nothing battery related, I checked for update in device manager, all is up to date.

I found a last thing to try which was to perform a power reset. I turned off the device, unplugged any usb devices on it and press the power button for 60 seconds. I turned it back on, nothing changed.

So, the question finally after all this, sorry for the interminable intro, do you guys have any clue about this problem? Device is ASUS ROG laptop model GL752V, tech info are:

16 gb DDR4 ram;
I7-6700HQ (skylake socket);
MOBO: GL752VW (as per CPUZ);
Windows 10 x64 v1903

I hope I provided enough info, but feel free to ask for anything else I would have forget. And thank you very much in advance!

Comment: Asus original replacement [battery](https://en.accessoires-asus.com/battery-a41n1611-for-rog-strix-68487-61494.htm#gl752vw|l). Battery with the same features found on [Amazon](https://www.amazon.com/A41N1611-Laptop-Battery-GL753V-GL752VW/dp/B07CH75ZYQ/ref=sr_1_80)

Comment: As I mentioned before, I highly doubt it has anything to do with hardware. I may be wrong, but many updates of software brought some changes in the issue. I'd like to troubleshoot as much as possible on the software side before purchasing a new battery or a new AC adapter.

Comment: Same battery problem on other laptops of the same model [1](https://rog.asus.com/forum/showthread.php?94593-GL752VW-DH74-Battery-0-not-charging) [2](https://rog.asus.com/forum/showthread.php?104865-ROG-GL752V-Battery-Problems) [3](https://www.reddit.com/r/techsupport/comments/6zp3y5/battery_problems/)